# a func called count and this func accepts 2 parameters and it'll return a string.If count(0,5).output: 0,1,2,3,4,5.I only slove this prblm in array

Tags: javascript

```js
function count(param1, param2) {
  let value = [];
  for (let i = param1; i <= param2; i++) {
    value.push(i);
  }
  return value;
}
let countNumber = count(0, 10);
console.log(countNumber);
```

I want to show it as a string like `0,1,2,3,4,5`. But I can't solve this problem. I can only solve this as an array. My output is `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: `return value.join(",")`

Comment: You can also do `value.toString()` or `\`${value}\``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array elements back into a string, and return that from your function.

```js
function count(param1, param2) {
  const value = [];
  for (let i = param1; i <= param2; i++) {
    value.push(i);
  }
  return value.join(',');
}

const countNumber = count(0, 5);

console.log(countNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function count (start, end) {
    console.log(Array.from({length: end-start+1}, (v, k) => k+start).join(","));
}
```

Comment: Since the end is inclusive, this should be `end - start + 1`.

Comment: This is so weirdly convoluted. Why choose this method when all the OP needs to do is `join` up the array they've produced with a very simple loop? You haven't commented your code, or provided any links to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
function count(param1, param2) {
  let value = [];
  for (let i = param1; i <= param2; i++) {
    value.push(i);
  }
  return value;
}
let countNumber = count(0, 10);
console.log(countNumber.toString());
```